# Third party replacements for MediaPlayer/MediaRecorder?

Tags: android

The built-in classes for working with audio in Android seem less than ideal. To me, they are overly complex to use, yet provide only basic functionality.

However, I don't wish to start a debate about the merits or shortcomings of these classes. I just want to know: are there any libraries to provide alternatives to recording and playing audio in Android? I have not been able to find anything, but perhaps there is something out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/) looks pretty good, though I have never use it myself. One of interesting feature they say is support HTTP Live Streaming on Android 2.1+. worth to check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That isn't what I'm looking for, but it's good to know that there is at least one MediaPlayer replacement--and hopefully there are more. :) I don't know about the streaming--I thought MediaPlayer already did that, but maybe Vitamio does it better. Vitamio can be used in commercial apps, works with video subtitles and more file formats, but requires the app user to download the Vitamio library to their phone, and uses the MediaPlayer interface--so it doesn't simplify anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Accepted since there are no other answers.